# fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Python33\Lib.obj'

Tags: visual-studio-2005, boost-python

I have been encountering a bug in Visual Studio 2005. I used `boost python` (boost_1_54_0) to interface python 3.3.2 to c++. I followed this tutorial.

http://www.thalesians.com/finance/index.php/Knowledge_Base/CPP/Boost_Python_Step_By_Step.

and from StackOverflow questions

[Visual Studio: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451324/visual-studio-link-fatal-error-lnk1181-cannot-open-input-file)

I included the required library in linker input, but I'm still getting this linking error:

```
fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Python33\Lib.obj'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove this error add Additional Dependencies in the Linker.
Project prperties-->Configuration Properties-->Linker-->Input -->Additional Dependencies
and then add following Libarary

c:\python33\libs\python33.lib.

Hope this resolove the error.