# Linking issue with OpenCV Lib after changing to x64 (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation

I just wanted to compile my C++ program into x64.

I didn't change anything else, but now I get following error:
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'opencv_calib3d249d.lib'

win32 still works fine though.
(I used this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451324/visual-studio-link-fatal-error-lnk1181-cannot-open-input-file)

Comment: Where you've got OpenCV? Have you built it by yourself or set it up from installer?

Comment: Do you have an x64 build of opencv for Visual Studio 2010? The 32 bit version will not work for x64 builds. Also remember when you use binaries make sure you use the one in the vc10 folder. You can not use opencv builds that were built with any other compiler (because that would create 2 independent heaps which leads to heap corruption and random looking application crashes)

Comment: "I didn't change anything else" - you will have to adjust the linker path from x86 to x64 (so it finds the correct libs)