# fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'mylib.lib' when linking .lib and .def file

Tags: dll, linker, .lib

I am trying to link a .lib file and a .def file to create a .dll of this .lib file. I have been using this command:     link /dll /machine:x86 /def:mylib.def  mylib.lib   and have been receiving the LNK 1181 error message. As noted on other stack posts ([Visual Studio: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451324/visual-studio-link-fatal-error-lnk1181-cannot-open-input-file)), I have added the .lib path to my linker input directory and my additional library directory. Also, I have checked to make sure there are no spaces in the paths. I have tried everything noted in the post linked above.

Anyone have an idea as to what might be causing this error?

Thanks

Comment: ***Anyone have an idea as to what might be causing this error?*** The library could be corrupt. The library could be in the wrong folder. The library could be 32 bit when you are compiling a 64 bit project.. You could have typed the wrong filename in to your settings...

Comment: I have checked all of those possibilities and they do not seem to be the issue. @drescherjm