# LNK1181 Error, C++: Got a sample project but facing LNK1181 and theres nothing in the input

Tags: c++

I got a sample project from someone. I tried to compile it and got LINK1181

```
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file 'C:\Users\USER_NAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PROJECT_NAME\x64\Debug\PROJECT_NAME_LIB_FILE.lib'  TryingStuff_UnitTestsProject
```

Where PROJECT_NAME is the name of the pc of the user that provided that sample project to me.
Now, I looked  everywhere, I couldn't find leftovers whatsoever for that particular user name. Nor in the input of 'Linker' under Properties.
Any idea where might this be coming from?

Many thanks

Comment: Open the `.vcxproj` file in a text editor and search for that string. There are too many places where that setting can hide and only you have the file.

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451324/visual-studio-link-fatal-error-lnk1181-cannot-open-input-file

Comment: There is more than one way to specify a link dependency, it can also be done in code with #pragma comment(lib, "yadayada").  But certainly best to talk to this "someone" so we don't have to guess.