# Link error when trying to run qhull cpp example

Tags: c++, qt, qhull

I was trying to run Qhull provided src/user_eg3 in visual studio 2019

I have installed Qt extension on my VS, Qt 6.0 also installed
When I loaded .pro file and tried to build .pro that includes user_eg3.cpp

Additional included library has included src/libqhull_r and src/libqhullcpp these two folders

When I was building, keep getting below error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file 'qhullcpp_d.lib' user_eg3    C:\Users\kli\Documents\awrpdk15\CoreProc\External\qhull-2020.2\src\user_eg3\LINK    1

I have searched the entire library, there is no qhullcpp_d.lib under the entire folder,
since this is my first time run Qt pro, can anyone point me out what is the potential reason causing this failure?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about the configuration I'm taking a guess here because have faced this error a lot. make sure in linker "Project properties -> Linker -> General -> Link Library Dependencies.  you should also look at project dependency and change it accordingly.     This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451324/visual-studio-link-fatal-error-lnk1181-cannot-open-input-file

Comment: but issue is that I do not even know where does " qhullcpp_d.lib" came from, I do have external include library called qhullcpp and it has been linked. currently, I do not know how this mysterious .lib file got generated